# Use date_select without showing a day

Tags: ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the rails date_select to prompt users to pick year, month and day. However, I would like to only list prompt users to enter just year and month without showing the day field. I want the day to always be 20th of any month of any year. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
date_select @foo, :date_of_foo, { discard_day: true }
```

will get rid of the date part; unfortunately it is incompatible with

```
date_select @foo, :date_of_foo, { default: { day: 20 } }
```

which would pre-set the (now omitted) day select to `20`; instead, the day is set to `1`, so you will have to adjust the day manually when you receive it (or hack the `date_select` result to change the hidden field's value from `1` to `20`).

Comment: I guess so. The only way I think I can hack that is to manually update each field in my controller. But in my  controller,  what I did was to create a private method to list out all my params and in my update, I just update params and save. Does this mean I'd have to manually update each parameter in my update method?

Comment: Yes, that is probably best. This also works, but it is a massive hack: `(date_select @foo, :date_of_foo, { discard_day: true }).gsub(/(\[date_of_foo\(3i\)\].*?)"1"/, '\1"20"')`